# SQL Plus SYSDATE Usage?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, sqlplus

i have asked a previous question about the same schema however im writing out how to solve this problem and i remember hearing something about `SYSDATE` but i am kinda unsure about what it is and how to use it properly... heres the schema, the problem and my attempt.

Problem:  A view named `ProblematicMachine` that lists all information about the machines,
for which more than 5 tickets where opened during the previous month (i.e., if
we run the view in Oct, then it lists tickets for which more than 5 tickets where
submitted in Sep, and if we run it in Nov, it list tickets for which more than 5
tickets where submitted in Oct, and so on)

My solution without the `SYSDATE`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ProblematicMachine AS 
SELECT machine_name, IP, network_port, MACADDR, location_id 
FROM Inventory, Tickets
WHERE    *this is where i was gonna use the condition of the 
 SYSDATE i guess SYSDATE - 30 (for days).
```

### SCHEMAS

```
TECH PERSONNEL (pplSoft, fname, lname, pittID, expertise, office phone) 
where fname is first name, and lname is last name.

USERS (pplSoft, fname, lname, pittID, office phone)

CATEGORIES (category id, category, description) where this table lists 
all possible categories of submitted tickets.

INVENTORY(machine name, IP, network port, MACADDR, location id)

LOCATIONS(location id, location, building, notes)

TICKETS (ticket number, owner pplSoft, date submitted, date closed, 
days worked on, category id, machine name, location, description)

ASSIGNMENT (ticket number, tech pplSoft, date assigned, status) 
where status held is an enumeration, could be: assigned, 
in progress, delegated, closed successful, or closed unsuccessful.
```

Comment: "SYSDATE - 30" is correct syntax for subtracting a number of days, but which column name and data type are you using for the comparison?

Comment: I can't tell what your question is. Are you just asking what `SYSDATE` is and how to use it? If so, then it would make more sense to [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=sysdate) than to post your entire schema here . . .

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking how to find out what tickets were opened last month, you'd want something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM tickets
 WHERE trunc( date_opened, 'MM' ) = trunc( add_months(sysdate,-1), 'MM' );
```

A function-based index on `trunc( date_openend, 'MM' )` would be helpful from a performance standpoint for this sort of query (assuming you are eventually going to have many months worth of data).  If you want to utilize an index on just `date_opened`, you'd need something more like

```
SELECT *
  FROM tickets
 WHERE date_opened >= trunc( add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM' )
   AND date_opened <  trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )
```

If you are asking something else, you'll have to be a bit more specific.

In your proposed view, you're not specifying any join conditions.  You'll need some join conditions in order to join two tables together.